# Scope request cxf jaxrs

Tags: scope, jax-rs, cxf

I would like to ask you a question about the scoping of the beans with cxf.
According to the documentation all the bean will in scope singleton. However I would like to have them in scope request.

In the doc here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html

I found:

> When service classes and providers are registered this way, the default life-cycle is 'singleton'. You can override it by setting a "jaxrs.scope" parameter with the value of 'prototype' (equivalent to per-request).

I tried thousand of stuff and I was not able to make them working:

Here is my web xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>CxfRestService</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/resource/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.scope</param-name>
            <param-value>request</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

I did a simple test with this:

```
@Path("/")
@WebService(name = "profile", targetNamespace = "")
@Named
public class ProfileCXFService {

    private String thisIsAValue;
    /**
     * Create a profile
     */
    @POST
    @Path("")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response createProfile(Profile profile){

        if(thisIsAValue == null){
            thisIsAValue = "toto";
        } else{
            return Response.serverError().entity("NOOOOOO").build();
        }
        return Response.ok().entity("YESSSSS").build();
    }
```

The first call is YESSS and the second NOOOOO.

I would like to have all my beans as request. Were can I find a common way to configure this.

In fact I do not have problem with singleton as the only fields I have are services which are as well singleton and the only moment where I need to use fields specific to the request I am doing a new MyObject. However I heard that Singleton can cause latency if the traffic grows on the server.

Do you have any idea of what can I do?

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards

Geoffrey

Answer (score -1):

So basically found the solution:

In your beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <jaxrs:server id="profile" address="/profile">
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="ProfileCXFServiceImpl"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="ProfileCXFServiceImpl" class="com.project.cxfrestservice.ProfileCXFServiceImpl" scope="prototype"><aop:scoped-proxy /></bean>

</beans>
```

And Voila!!!!